# Spring boot web service Android java localhost problem

Tags: java, android, json, spring

**My Android Manifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.zaurfarrukhzada.htmlparsingapp">

     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />//This is my internet permission


      <application
         android:allowBackup="true"
         android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
         android:label="@string/app_name"
         android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
         android:supportsRtl="true"
         android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
         android:theme="@style/Theme.HtmlParsingApp">
          <activity android:name=".View.MainActivity">
              <intent-filter>
                 <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
             </intent-filter>
          </activity>
      </application>

  </manifest>
```

**My model**

```
public class City implements Serializable {//this is my model city 

     @SerializedName("id")
     @Expose
     private Integer id;
     @SerializedName("name")
     @Expose
     private String name;
     @SerializedName("countryCode")
     @Expose
     private String countryCode;
     @SerializedName("district")
     @Expose
     private String district;
     @SerializedName("population")
     @Expose
      private Integer population;

     public Integer getId() {
      return id;
     }

      public void setId(Integer id) {
      this.id = id;
      }

     public String getName() {
        return name;
      }

      public void setName(String name) {
     this.name = name;
      }

     public String getCountryCode() {
       return countryCode;
     }

     public void setCountryCode(String countryCode) {
      this.countryCode = countryCode;
     }

    public String getDistrict() {
       return district;
     }

     public void setDistrict(String district) {
        this.district = district;
     }

    public Integer getPopulation() {
        return population;
     }

    public void setPopulation(Integer population) {
        this.population = population;
       }
   }
```

**My Rest Api interface**

```
   public interface RestApi 
  {
   @GET("cities")
    Call<List<City>> getAllCities(); //My models request the spring boot web service  
 }
```

**My ManagerAll Class**

```
public class ManagerAll extends  BaseManager 
 {

private static ManagerAll ourInstance = new ManagerAll();
public static  synchronized ManagerAll getInstance(){
    return  ourInstance;
}

public Call<List<City>>  getAllCities(){
    Call<List<City>> allCities = getRestClientCities().getAllCities();//Call restapi 
    return  allCities;
  }
}
```

**My RestApiClient Class**  //this is Restapiclient connect retrofit and okhhtpi

```
  public class RestApiClient {
  private RestApi mGetResApi;

    public RestApiClient(String restApiServiceUrl){

    OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .writeTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .connectTimeout(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);


    OkHttpClient okHttpClient = builder.build();
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(restApiServiceUrl)
            .client(okHttpClient)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    mGetResApi = retrofit.create(RestApi.class);
}

public RestApi getRestApi(){
    return mGetResApi;
   }
   }
```

**My BaseManager Class**  this is basemanager send data the restapiclient

```
   public class BaseManager {
     protected RestApi getRestClientCities(){
        RestApiClient restApiClient = new RestApiClient(BaseUrl.BASE_URL);
       return restApiClient.getRestApi();
     }
     }
```

**My BaseUrl Class** // this is base url

```
 public class BaseUrl {
    public static final String BASE_URL="http://192.168.x.x:8080/";//this my spring boot webservice localhost 
 }
```

**My MainActivity Class**

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    requestCities();
}


public void requestCities(){
     Call<List<City>> call = ManagerAll.getInstance().getAllCities();
    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<City>>() {
         @Override
         public void onResponse(Call<List<City>> call, Response<List<City>> response) {
             Log.i("city",response.body().toString());
         }

         @Override
         public void onFailure(Call<List<City>> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.i("log",t.getLocalizedMessage());
             Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, t.getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         }
     });
   }
  }
```

**My json cities**

```
      http://localhost:8080/cities  ///Spring boot data in web service 



  {  
      {
     "id": 1,
      "name": "Kabul",
      "countryCode": "AFG",
      "district": "Kabol",
     "population": 1780000
     },
      {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Qandahar",
       "countryCode": "AFG",
       "district": "Qandahar",
      "population": 237500
       },
       {
         "id": 3,
         "name": "Herat",
       "countryCode": "AFG",
        "district": "Herat",
        "population": 186800
        },
        {
           "id": 4,
         "name": "Mazar-e-Sharif",
          "countryCode": "AFG",
          "district": "Balkh",
          "population": 127800
         },
        {
          "id": 5,
         "name": "Amsterdam",
         "countryCode": "NLD",
         "district": "Noord-Holland",
         "population": 731200
         }
}
```

**My problem is I want to get the web service that I wrote with spring boot, but localhost is the localhost and post of the android phone and the computer is not the same. What can I do?
Please help me,Thanks**

Comment: I think it is about firewall problem, If you can get the list from postman.You can check it by using telnet for android. if you cannot access the port via telnet, check these steps in the link. https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-disable-the-windows-firewall-2624505

Comment: Wouldn't it be a problem to shut down a firewall

Comment: After you test your API, you should turn it on again.

Comment: problem is solved seyid Thanksss

Comment: But I always turn off the firewali. Is there any other solution?

Comment: No problem, glad to hear it:)

Comment: Isn't there a way without a firewall without shutting down?

Comment: You can only open the firewall for a specific port. I think it will be safer this way. I never test it in windows, but you can check it in this link https://www.windowscentral.com/how-open-port-windows-firewall

Comment: Obviously you can allow the port `8080` from firewall - and don't shut down on all the firewall.! Or you can chane also port 8080 from Spring to another port also...